# error - a bean of type 'package' while injecting dependency of one service into another services controller[Spring-Boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a jar library where one service declaration looks like this

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class ABC {
```

Now I have imported this jar file using maven pom.xml in different service and
where my code looks like this

```
    import a.b.ABC


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("")
    @Slf4j
    public class xyz {
    @Autowired
    private ABC abcd;
```

When compiling with mvn clean install, this is the error, I am getting

> {"json_mssg": {"date": "21-07-2021 20:29:06.653", "thread": "main",
> "level": "ERROR", "log":
> "**newline____newline*******************************newline__APPLICATION FAILED TO
> START__newline*****************************__newline____newline__Description:__newline____newline__Field abcd in x.y.z.xxController required a bean of
> type 'a.b.ABC' that could not be
> found.__newline____newline__The injection point has the following
> annotations:**newline**   -
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)__newline____newline____newline__Action:__newline____newline__Consider defining a bean of type 'glance.content.server.beacon.BeaconFactory'
> in your configuration.**newline**", "logger":
> "org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter",
> "method": "report", "ex": ""}}
>
> How can I initialise the object or how can I use the object of ABC
> here ?? I am very new to spring and java.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Import(ABC.class) on your SpringBootApplication class or create bean where you inited and configured ABC class (@Configuration+@Bean)

Comment: currently code is like this for ABC
@Service
public class ABC {

Comment: you are saying to add both these annotations. is it?

Comment: @Import(ABC.class) or (@Configuration+@Bean)